# Help needed for implementing a thread Monitoring Mechanism

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I am working on a multithreaded middleware enviornment. The framework is basically a capturing and streaming framework. So it involves a number of threads.

To give you all a brief idea of the threading architecture: 
There are seprate threads for **demultiplexer**, **receiveVideo**, **DecodeVideo**, **DisplayVideo** etc. Each thread performs its functionlity, for eg:
**demultiplexer** extracts audio, video packets
**receivevideo** receives header + payload of video packet & removes payload
**DecodeVideo** receives payload & decodes payload packet
**DisplayVideo** receives decoded packets & displays the decoded packets on display

Thus each thread feeds the extracted data to the next thread. The threads share data buffers amongst them and the buffers are synchronised through use of mutexes and semaphores. Similarly, there are other threads for handling **ananlogvideo** and **analogaudio** etc.

All the threads are spawned in during **initialization** but they remain blocked on a semaphore and depending upon the input(analog/digitial) selective semaphores are signalled so that specifc threads get unblocked & move on to do their work. At various stages each thread calls some lower level(driver calls)to get data or write data etc. These calls are blocking and the errors resulting from these calls(driver returning corrupted data, driver stalling) should be handled but are not being handled currently.

I wanted to implement a **thread monitoring mechanism** where a thread will monitor these worker threads and if an error condition occurs will take some preventive actions. As I understand certain such mechanisms are commonly used like Watchdogs in UI or MMI applications. I am trying to look for something similar.

I am using pthreads and No Boost or STL(its a legacy code, pretty much procedural C++)

Any ideas about specific framework or design patterns or open source projects which do something similar and might help in with ideas for implementing my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Can you ping the threads - periodically send each one a message on its usual input queue, interleaved with all the other normal stuff, asking it to return its status?  When each handler thread gets the message, it loads the message with status stuff - how many messages its processed since the last ping, length of its input/output queue,  last time that its driver returned OK, that sort of stats - and queues it back to your Thread Monitoring Mechanism.  Your TMM would have to time out the replies in case some thread/s is/are stuck.

You could, maybe, just post one message down the whole chain, each thread adding its own status in different fields.  That would mean only one timeout, after which your TMM would have to examine the message to see how far down the chain it got.

There are other things - I like to keep an on-screen dump, on a 1s timer, of the length of queues and depth of buffer pools.  If something stuffs, I can usually tell roughly where it is, (eg. a pool is emptying and some queue is growing - the queue comsumer is wasted).

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

What about using a signalling system to wake up your monitoring thread when something's gone awry in one of your worker threads.  You can emulate the signalling with an ResetEvent of some type.

When an exception occurs in your worker thread, you have some data structure you fill up with the data about the exception and then you can pass that on to your monitoring thread.  You wake up the monitoring thread by using the event.

Then the monitoring thread can do what you need it to do.

I'm guessing you don't wish to have your monitoring thread active unless something has gone wrong, right?

Comment: I could have the monitor thread active only on exceptions or keep it awake and polling all the time, it's all upon my implementation but the problem with signalling is, I would need to know exception has occured or an error condition which tells me so, which is not possible always like if driver stalls indefinitely or sends out corrupted junk.

Comment: @Als I'm not sure that you can ever know if a driver stalls or not. I don't know of any mechanism by which you can detect if a driver stalls.  You can however know if an exception occurs by having a try catch and inside the catch you have a signalling mechanism. See it could be part of your exception handling mechanism